# How to test HTTP2 client implementation?

Tags: http2

Is there any way to test all the nasty edge cases of **HTTP2** client-side protocol implementation?

There's a https://httpbin.org for **HTTP/1.x**, what about **HTTP2**?

Comment: Even though I usually ignore SJW, can anybody explain to me what's exactly off-topic about this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not as comprehensive but the best online test fro HTTP/2 I have found so far is at https://http2.golang.org - it did help me to find the "edge cases"

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately http2.golang.org does not accept new req over http/2. It need to  be connected HTTP/1 way and then connection state needs to be changed.

Comment: It does accept HTTP2 without upgrade from HTTP/1.1 - tested with `curl --http2-prior-knowledge https://http2.golang.org`